# How to debug module (tweepy) working locally but not in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, tweepy

I have seen similar questions but mine is a bit different. I am trying to use the Twitter API Tweepy inside Google App Engine cron jobs, and it is working just fine up until the last line:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status('test')
```

If I comment out the last line, the cron job executes successfully (but obviously doesn't update my status). If I include the last line, I receive a "500 Internal Server Error" when I execute the cron job.

This script works perfectly if I run it locally through IDLE or whatever. I guess I have a couple questions from this experience:

1. Has anyone had a similar issue with Tweepy in GAE?
2. How do I get more debug information from GAE? I tried placing try/catches around the line and logging the exception, but I still just get a "500 error". This is the same error I get if there is even a syntax mistake. Anything at all wrong gives ma 500 error so it is pretty challenging to debug real issues. I am on Windows 8 running the server locally through GAE Launcher if that makes a difference. I haven't found any real help in their documentation on the proper way to debug.

Comment: view the logs for more debug info, when deployed.

Comment: I have the exact same problem right now. Here is the exception on dev_appserver:

`TweepError: Failed to send request: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))`

It doesn't work when uploaded neither.